# What is the best Java OXM library?

Tags: java, oxm

Even though I've been a developer for awhile I've been lucky enough to have avoided doing much work with XML. So now I've got a project where I've got to interact with some web services, and would like to use some kind of Object-to-XML Mapping solution.

The only one I'm aware of is JAXB. Is that the best to go with? Are there any other recommendations?

One catch - I'm stuck using Java 1.4, so I can't do anything with annotations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're calling a web-service with a WSDL, JAXB is absolutely the best option. Take a look at wsimport, and you're be up and running in 10 minutes.

I don't think JAXB 2.0 will be possible on Java 1.4. You may need to use Axis instead:

```
java -cp axis-1.4.jar;commons-logging-1.1.jar;commons-discovery-0.2.jar;jaxrpc-1.1.jar;saaj-1.1.jar;wsdl4j-1.4.jar;activation-1.1.jar;mail-1.4.jar org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java http://someurl?WSDL
```

This will generate similar stubs to JAXB.

If you don't have a WSDL or XSD, you can always [generate one](http://bitkickers.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-jaxb-without-schema.html).

Answer (score 10):

**JAXB is the best choice:**

- [Public API included in Java SE 6](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/package-summary.html)
- Binding layer for JAX-WS (Web Services)
- Binding layer for JAX-RS (Rest)
- [Can preserve XML Infoset](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html)
- Multiple implementations:  [Metro](http://jaxb.java.net/), [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), [JaxMe](http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/), etc

**[EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) is the best implementation:**

MOXy is a JAXB implementation with Extensions

MOXy has an external configuration file (based on JAXB annotations with extensions):

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/EclipseLink-OXM.XML

Has XPath based mapping, for deep mapping:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Designed to handle ORM mapped objects, including support for bidirectional relationships:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JPA
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html

Answer (score 3):

There's [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). I seem to remember I used that ages ago, and it was fine. Can't say I have enough experience to recommend it for or against, but it's worth checking out just as an alternative.

Comment: XStream is awesome for Java object -> XML. It's not ideal for the reverse. Assuming you have a WSDL or XSD, JAXB is better at the latter.

Comment: In my experience, XStream is always very tempting to start with, since it's so easy, but then it ends up being so buggy that I always abandon it for JAXB eventually.

Answer (score 3):

JIBX - known for performance

JAXB2 - Ease of use

Castor - Ease of use

others - 
XMLBean, 
Xstream